# How to avoid deadlocks in PessimisticLockScope.EXTENDED?

Tags: sql, hibernate, isolation-level, database-deadlocks, pessimistic-locking

I’m creating a Java transfer money app that basically transfers money from one account to another.

In a nutshell I have a `Transfer` entity that contains 3 properties: `@ManyToOne OriginAccount`, `@ManyToOne TargetAccount` and `Amount`.

Account contains a balance to be adjust within the transfer.

I’m about to use `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` on `Account` entities but I have to consider a deadlock.

One option is to select list of 2 accounts always in the same order (sort based on id) to always acquire locks in the same order.

I also heard about `PessimisticLockScope.EXTENDED` but what will be the order of locks acquiring on joined records? Is there any option to ensure the order based on a kinda comparator? How can I certainly exclude a deadlock possibility?